# How to Grant All Privileges for All Databases except one in Hive SQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I know how to grant privileges on a database to a role in Hive SQL.

For example, 
    GRANT ALL ON DATABASE analyst1 TO ROLE analyst_role;

But there are hundreds of databases on my system, it's almost impossible to grant one by one.

Is it possible to grant all privileges for all databases except one database(ex: db.name = temp)?